# Is the usage of word, “Deck” as a package of paper limited to cards?

Tags: word-usage

I felt nostalgic to find the word ‘copy deck’ in the latest EL& U question, “Is subcopy a word?”followed with the statement:

> “A copywriter just sent me over a **copy deck** that had the word
>   subcopy to describe the text immediately after the page title.”

I remember that when I was working in an ad agency, expatriate staffs, particularly my senior who happened to be British liked to use the word “deck” for the package of presentation documents and a set of handouts at the meeting. I followed his suit.

Seeing the word, “Copy deck” again after long time, I checked online dictionaries to reconfirm whether I had rightly used the word, ‘deck’ around that time, and was embarrassed to find none of Cambridge, Oxford, Merriam-Webster, and OALED registers the definitions of “Deck” other than (1) a floor of ship, (2) a package of cards, and (3) a component or unit for playing records, or recording tapes, or compact discs.

Beside ‘a floor of a ship,’
Cambridge English Dictionary defines ‘deck’ as: (mainly US) a set of cards used for playing card games.
Oxford Dictionary defines: (1) chiefly North American, a pack of cards. (2) a component or unit for playing or recording records, tapes, or compact discs: a cassette deck
Merriam -Webster Dictionary simply defines: a pack of playing cards.

Is it far-stretched to use “deck” for a package of items (documents, exhibits, and writings) as we had used to and as used in the question other than cards?
Were we using the word wrong way?

Comment: People also refer to "slide decks"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If embarrassment belongs anywhere, it belongs with the publishers of the dictionaries, not with you. *Century Dictionary and Cyclopedia*, found at [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/deck), includes this definition:

> **deck** *n*. A pile of things laid one upon another; a heap; a store; a file, as of cards or papers.

In short, you were using the word legitimately.

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/deck

Comment: OED treats that sense as no longer in use, with the last examples from the 17th century.

Comment: This is not the answer.

Comment: Legitimate, but the usage is not very common. It is liable to cause significant confusion without abundant context!

Comment: I haven't found this usage to be all that common, either, but it wouldn't surprise me if it _was_ rather common in a specialized domain, such as print advertising, as part of "trade speak."

Answer (score 5):

Here are the fifth and sixth senses from the OED entry (note that the latter is considered "dead"). I don't think that the usage you are proposing is too far-fetched. It's just too localised to make it into the dictionaries. If you have some textual citations you might consider sending a letter to OED, as they are always on the lookout for missing words.

> 5.
>    a. ‘A pack of cards piled regularly on each other’ (Johnson); also the portion of the pack left, in some games, after the hands have been dealt. Since 17th c. dial. and in U.S.
>   
>   1594   Selimus sig. F4v,   If I chance but once to get the decke, To deale about and shufle as I would.
>   1594   R. Barnfield Shepheard Content viii. sig. Eiij,   Pride deales the Deck whilst Chance doth choose the Card.
>   1595   Shakespeare Henry VI, Pt. 3 v. i. 44   But whilst he sought to steale the single ten, The king was finelie fingerd from the decke.
>   1609   R. Armin Hist. Two Maids More-clacke sig. D1v,   Ile deale the cards and cut ye from the decke.
>   1701   N. Grew Cosmol. Sacra i. iii. §21   The Selenites [have the shape], of Parallel Plates, as in a Deck of Cards.
>   1777   J. Brand Observ. Pop. Antiq. (1849) II. 449   In some parts of the North of England a pack of cards is called to this day..a deck of cards.
>   1860   in J. R. Bartlett Dict. Americanisms (ed. 3)   
>   1882   B. Harte Gentl. La Porte in Flip 135,   I reckon the other fifty-one of the deck ez as pooty.
>   1884   R. Holland Gloss. Words County of Chester (1886) ,   Deck o' cards, a pack of cards.
>   1885   Cent. Mag. 29 548/1   An old ratty deck of cards.
>   
>    b. A packet of narcotics; a small portion of some drug wrapped in paper. U.S. slang.
>   
>   1922   E. F. Murphy Black Candle (1926) i. v. 52   Small paper packages [of cocaine]..are called ‘decks’, and contain about a couple of sniffs.
>   1927   Flynn's 9 July 462/2   At night it was ‘snow’ that went over the counter..to poor devils who left behind them three dollars..for a deck.
>   1949   ‘J. Evans’ Halo in Brass (1951) iv. 29   A deck of nose candy for sale to the right guy.
>   1966   C. Himes Heat's On iii. 27   When it's analysed, they'll find five or six half-chewed decks of heroin.
>   
>   
>   †6.
>    a. A pile of things laid flat upon each other.
>   
>   1625   F. Markham Bk. Honour ii. vi. 63   Any whose Pedigree lyes so deepe in the decke, that few or none will labour to find it.
>   1631   J. Mabbe tr. F. de Rojas Spanish Bawd xix. 185   Subtill words, whereof such as shee are never to seeke, but have them still ready in the deck.
>   1634   R. Sanderson Serm. II. 287   So long as these things should hang upon the file, or lie in the deck, he might perhaps be safe.
>   1673   A. Marvell Rehearsal Transpros'd II. 394   A certain Declaration..which you have kept in deck until this season.
>   
>  
>    b. Part of a newspaper, periodical, etc., headline containing more than one line of type, esp. the part printed beneath the main headline. Also attrib.
>   
>   1935   H. Straumann Newspaper Headlines i. 28   These are first decks (and streamers) only.
>   1935   H. Straumann Newspaper Headlines iii. 87   The first three lines or ‘decks’ as they would be called in present-day journalism.
>   1965   L. H. Whitten Progeny of Adder (1966) 127   The eight-column headline told him of Pantelein's body being found. But it was the ‘deck’ headline that held him: county coroner cites ‘vampirism’.

Comment: The newspaper usage identified here is certainly consistent with the reference to "copy deck" from the OP; but appears not to be related to "a package of items" as he inferred.

Comment: @Foltier. I didn’t say a package of any ‘items.’ I said we called a package (set) of ‘papers’ such as a file of documents including proposals, supporting data, and exhibits we used for client presentation and handouts used at the meeting a “(presentation) deck” at an ad agency.

Answer (score 5):

"Deck" is a common term in [news style writing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/News_style):

> **Subhead** (or **dek** or **deck**)
>   A phrase, sentence or several sentences near the title of an article or story, a quick blurb or article teaser.

Answer (score 2):

As long as they're stacked. A stack of punch-cards (which is quite a different thing to a deck of playing cards) is called a deck. Like playing cards, they're in a stack and it's been suggested that this was by analogy to ships' decks or items stacked on them.

Even if it wasn't common, it should be clear.

Comment: My recollection of this usage (_Place the appropriate header cards on the deck before placing it in the reader._) is that it rested upon the physical similarity of each item. When I placed a 6x4 file card between decks stored in box, the result was not a deck but a collection of decks. By analogy a pile of papers in different formats would not be a deck but a heap?

Answer (score 2):

I am a stupid American, and I've heard **deck** used when describing a collection of slides, PowerPoint or otherwise. Calling it a deck, rather than a presentation, differentiates the collection of prepared visuals from the style, manner and delivery used by the presenter.